Avoiding secondary flow in rotating fluid
I am required to create an annular flume for an experiment. The flume is to be filled with water, and a paddle is to be dipped into the water and rotated along the flume at some fixed angular velocity to set the water into a rotational motion. This is going to be done so that we can get a nearly straight water flow near the bottom of the flume (the radius-to-flume width ratio is large).
While researching for potential problems that I could encounter, I found out about the Einstein Tea Leaves Paradox. This involves a secondary flow inward that creates a vortex-like motion in the rotating fluid. I need to avoid this in order to get the straight fluid flow parallel to the flume near the bottom. A potential solution that I discovered was to counter-rotate the flume itself so that there is no eventual decrease of velocity in the boundary layer at the bottom (the cause of the secondary flow). Another solution that was suggested to me by my supervisor was to use an angled paddle, like the cone-and-plate apparatus that is used to study the rheological properties of minute samples. He suggested this because it would be able to provide me with a near-constant shear rate radially.
My question is this - how would that help me avoid the secondary flow in the flume?
Even if I spin the paddle at a constant angular velocity, the fluid is eventually going to reach a steady rotational motion at the same angular velocity. In that case too, there would be the boundary layer problem - the decrease in the speed near the boundary layer would reduce the centripetal force on a parcel of fluid near the bottom, causing it to move inwards. I tried, but can not figure out how constant shear rate figures into the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

According to Tea leaf paradox,

The stirring makes the water spin in the cup, causing a centrifugal force outwards. Near the bottom however, the water is slowed by friction. Thus the centrifugal force is weaker near the bottom than higher up, leading to a secondary circular (helical) flow that goes outwards at the top, down along the outer edge, inwards along the bottom, bringing the leaves to the center, and then up again


So add friction along the top by floating a non rotating lid. Add friction to the inside of the annulus by adding ridges to make the surface area equal to the outside.
Or if you only need a section of the annulus, fill the rest with straws to make the flow in the right direction: Making a Laminar Flow Nozzle! TKOR Teaches You How To Make Laminar Water Flow Fountain. You might use a pump instead of a paddle.

Thank you so much for the answer! Your solutions fit the bill! I was wondering though, will the constant shear applied by the angled paddle be of any help in this situation? Why/Why not? Apologies for my ignorance - I'm only an undergrad and do not know much fluid mechanics.

I would think a paddle of any sort would stir the water. It sounds like you want laminar flow, not turbulent flow. You might get better results if the paddle had a sliding seal and filled the channel, so that it formed a moving wall.

Alright, thanks for the help! Marking your answer as the solution.
